# Mongo backend not connecting when deploying to fly.io

Tags: node.js, mongodb, fly

I deployed an app to fly.io,the front end is showing up, but the backend isn't connecting.So, not seeing any backend data and unable to interact with mongoDB atlas. The logs that show can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eczdL.png

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have whitelisted the current IP address (which is used by fly.io) in the `Network Access` section. if you are unaware of the IP address which is used by fly.io then hit `allow access from anywhere` while adding the whitelisted address, like this:-
https://archive.org/download/unknown_297351239_769746014166984_3926262045850176722_n/unknown_297351239_769746014166984_3926262045850176722_n.png

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/18NS2eP.png i've done 'allow from anywhere' and also my own ip and tried with both. Same end result. Everything works fine on local